# php imagemagick or any other way to find x y coord of puzzle piece

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, pixel

[image: captcha]

[image: piece]

I have two images and I need to find X coord where starting piece of puzzle. At start we know just Y coord - for this image its **51**

Thats mean we can crop image in one pixel row at **Y-51** and work with it - I thinking in this way, but maybe we can do it another way?

Anyway I don't know what to do next - how to find X coord with imagemagick on php or in cli

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [`Imagick::subImageMatch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.subimagematch.php) method.

```php
$canvas = new Imagick("canvas.png");
$piece = new Imagick("piece.png");

$canvas->subImageMatch($piece, $offset, $similarity);
```

Where `$offset` will be updated with the sub-image match coordinates.

```php
var_dump($offset);
/*
array(4) {
  ["x"]=>
  int(213)
  ["y"]=>
  int(72)
  ["width"]=>
  int(55)
  ["height"]=>
  int(55)
 }
 */
```

And  `$similarity` will be updated with a float number representing how close the best match is.

```php
var_dump($similarity);
// float(0.34148957886102)
```

The `Imagick::subImageMatch()` will also return a "heat-map", but that's only useful for debugging scans.

```php
$matches = $canvas->subImageMatch($piece, $offset, $similarity);
$matches->writeImage('heatmap.png')
```

[image: heatmap.png]

Comment: thanks for this, but right result only for 12 images of 50, others very far from true, 50 and more pixels miss.